# WPF and Unity - No matching constructor found on type

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container

I want to use Unity in my WPF application using VS2012, I defined unity container as follows:

```
IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();
var window = unityContainer.Resolve<MainWindow>();
window.Show();
```

My window constructor looks as follows:

```
public MainWindow(IMainViewModel mainViewModel)
       {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = mainViewModel;
        }
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'No matching constructor found on type
>   'WPFClient.MainWindow'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod
>   directives to construct this type.' Line number '3' and line position
>   '9'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which file/location did you place the code in which you are registering the dependencies in the container and instantiating the main window?

Comment: protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your `App.xaml`, make sure that you have gotten rid of the `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` property being set. Since you have overriden the `OnStartup` of your application and provided a custom instance of the `MainWindow` you shouldn't be leaving the default [`StartupUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri.aspx) property being set in the App.xaml file and WPF desperately trying to instantiate a type without a default constructor.

Comment: I just spent a good deal of time wrestling with this bug - Expression Studio 4 tries to be clever and re-inserts the StartupUri based on the last control created.

Comment: Back here for the second time. I'd give you another up-vote if I could. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the excellent answer, after deleting the startup URI don't forget to call the startup method within your App.xaml declaration:

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.App"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public IContainer container { get; private set; }

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var dependencyConfigurator = new DependencyConfig();
            container = dependencyConfigurator.Configure();
            container.Resolve<WindowClassName>();
            MainWindow.Show();
        }        
    }
```